# Three Js simple Shader not working

Tags: three.js, webgl, shader

I am trying to run the following simple shader with three.js

```
mat = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  uniforms: {
    color: { type: 'v3', value: new THREE.Color(0xcccccc) }
  },
  vertexShader: 'attribute vec3 vert;\n'
              + 'void main() {\n' 
              + '  gl_Position = vec4(vert, 1.0);\n'
              + '}',
  fragmentShader: 'uniform vec3 color;\n'
                + 'void main() {\n'
                + '  gl_FragColor = vec4(color,1);\n'
                + '}'
})
```

The shaders compile but the object that has this material is invisible.

This should display the object in a constant light grey color.

When I run this with [kick.js shader editor](http://www.kickjs.org/example/shader_editor/shader_editor.html)
it works as expected.

Predefined materials all work great.

Am I missing something?

Comment: what is this shader supposed to do? what is the expected result?

Comment: probably to do with settings the gl_Position with the vert attribute. Are you sure it has a value? Take a look at some of the [three.js shader experiments](http://blog.2pha.com/experimenting-threejs-shaders-and-shadermaterial) I have been doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your vertex shader should be:

```
// Multiply each vertex by the model-view matrix and the projection matrix
// (both provided by Three.js) to get a final vertex position. 
gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
```